# Can't create Android Project. What's missing?

Tags: android, osx-snow-leopard, myeclipse

I'm using MyEclipse 10 on Mac OSX 10.6.8.  I installed the Android SDK and the Android ADT plugin.  I also made sure to install the SDK tools, the latest version of the platform, and I added the path to the tools directory to my $PATH.  When I try creating a new Android Project in Eclipse I get this message: "Your tools installation appears to be out of date (or not yet installed).  This wizard depends on templates distributed with the Android SDK Tools.".  What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what was missing:
I didn't configure the ADT plugin within eclipse:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Configure